# subset of a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$ with nonempty interior has positive outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

> Let $A\subset I=[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$, $a < b$ such that Int$(A) \neq \emptyset$. Show that $A$ has positive outer measure.

What I have so far:

Since Int$(A) \subseteq A$, by the monotonicity property of the outer measure we have

$m^*(\text{Int}(A)) \leq m^*(A)$.

Since Int$(A)$ is a nonempty open set in $\mathbb{R}$, Int$(A)$ is uncountable, thus $m^*(\text{Int}(A)) > 0$.

Comment: The Cantor set is uncountable, but has measure zero.

Comment: Hint: Open sets in $\mathbb R$ can be written as a countable unions of disjoint open intervals. Since the set is bounded here, these intervals are also finite.